What kind of logical fallacy is the "Who are you?" scene from Anger Management?
I was wondering what kind of fallacy to attribute to an encounter I once had and, after writing for a bit, realized that I could literally sum it up by pointing to this scene from Anger Management: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV4zHRnIUpU.
My real scenario involved arguing for an approach that a former boss deemed too risky. I provided a risk analysis, but it wasn't a formal "Risk Analysis" white paper... it was just an informal, itemized list in an email that covered anything that could go wrong. AFTER I submitted my risk analysis (but without ever referring to it as such), he suggested he was open to my approach but that I should do some risk analysis and present it to him so we could make an informed decision.
I'm like "wait... I just... did?"
So I'm sitting there wondering questions like:

Did he not read the email I sent or listen when I read it to him in person?
Did he listen, but think it wasn't enough?
Does he just want a formal "Risk Analysis" title slapped on top of a Word Document?
Or is this simply a defense mechanism?

As I'm writing this, it also occurs to me that a simplified way to express this situation would be when someone continues to ask for an answer to a question you've already answered.
This seems a little like gaslighting, but not exactly. Is there a more accurate term for this?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The usual nature of an argument is that you show that your conclusion B is the logical necessity following from the premises A. Now a fallacy occurs if the conclusion does not follow from the premises. For example your premises could just be a long list not related to the conclusion or they could use similar terms, but with a different meaning or the premises are in itself true but not when connected to the other premises and so on.
So the first thing you need to figure out is what's the argument in the first place. Like in anger management it seems to be something like:
Premise 1: Answering a question means supplying the information requested
Premise 2: Adam Sandler did not give the information requested.
Conclusion: Adam Standler did not answer the question

Now if an argument is valid, the conclusion must follow from the premises or in other words if the premises are true so MUST be the conclusion. So if answering is defined as supplying the information requested and if Adam Sandler doesn't do that, then Adam Sandler is not answering the question.
So this far the argument could be valid (not fallacious). The problem occurs in the evaluation of that argument, so in checking whether it's sound (that is whether it's valid AND whether the premises actually are true). Because it becomes apparent that "the information requested" is not defined.
So Adam Sandler does attempt to answer the question by supplying information, but is told that this is not the information requested that was requested.
Now in the movie I'd guess the kitchen psychological analysis would be something like: Jack Nicholson tries to enrage Adam Sandler and to that end accuses him of dodging the question by equivocation (while he himself resorts to ad hoc rescues to avoid Adam Sandler from answering). Then stresses that it's a SIMPLE question, so insinuating that he's stupid if he can't answer it and then straight up bullies him by making fun of him in front of the audience, for the very reasonably request to specify the question. Which you could probably read as straw man argument, because while Adam Sandler asks to hear what Lou had to say about himself to get an idea what he's expected to say, Jack Nicholson twists that request as if he had sad that Lou should define Adam Sandler (which is much easier to dispel than the actual request).
So when Adam Sandler realizes that he's the subject of hostility, can only fail logically because Jack Nicholson isn't playing fair and is alone with the observers and potential mediators not being on his side he first snaps, then realizes that is bad with relation to not being perceived as having a rage problem, tries to apologize, but is told by Jack Nicholson that his behavior was already the answer.
Now that assessment in and of itself could also be seen as argument:
Premise 1: People who become enraged without reason have a rage problem
Premise 2: Adam Sandler gets enraged for no reason
Conclusion: Adam Sandler has a rage problem.

Where the problematic part that makes this argument not sound, hides in Premise 2, namely that he does have a reason to get enraged. He's unjustly attacked, repeatedly humiliated, deprived of a common rational ground and been singled out and shown to be without support. Not to mention the probably overarching narrative of having the low ground in terms of needing the confirmation of not having a problem from the guy who likes to proof the opposite.
Though that's a movie where this scenario is specifically manufactured that way, in case of your risk analysis that might simply be a miscommunication. For example the difference between a formal and informal risk analysis could be as simple as a signature of yours that makes the difference between a short ad hoc thought and a legally binding assessment of risk (I don't actually know what the problem is I'm just spitballing).
So ideally that is just a miscommunication and you should address that. If that persists ask coworkers what a risk analysis boils down to and if that is still rejected, ask their superior, HR or whoever is responsible what this nonsense is about.
PS: Also with regards to these so called fallacies like "equivocation", "straw man" and "no true scotsman", it's actually important as to whether they are actually fallacies in these situations or whether they are just miscommunications and rhetorical devices. Like just because someone doesn't initially get the right meaning of a word does not mean that the argument itself is fallacious, just that natural language is more prone to confusion and ambiguities. Or if you describe a scenario by an analog to showcase that you've understood someone's point, you're not necessarily creating a straw man argument or if you clarify that you use a specific definition rather than a common one you might actually avoid and not fall victim to the no true scotsman. So it's much more important to find out what is the argument and where it goes wrong.

Enjoyable answer. I'm thinking maybe OPs workplace is a bunch of sheep and a bully, and he just became aware of that :-) "You can't win an argument with your boss."

@ScottRowe This was a former boss and he was actually really boss... one of my favorites ever. He just liked doing things the way he'd always learned and they were like a decade behind in some areas with technology and methods they were using. He had a point that it was a "risk" for them to move forward because it's not what he was used to and could cause him to make mistakes. But it's also a risk when, soon, no one will want to work for you and you're about to hit retiring age. He was more open than this post gives him credit for, but the post isn't really supposed to be about him.

@BVernon "Even if you're on the right track, you'll get run over if you just stand there."

Ah, I think "ad hoc rescues" hits really close to home. It's almost like a super version of that but slightly modified. The actual request doesn't have to be modified, per se, because it's so broad. It's also so broad that the asker can't be expected to give every possibility because "you don't know what you don't know". Yet no matter how many angles the respondant covers, there's always another angle to be found. I think the inverse would be like asking someone to shoot a target. They shoot it so many times that 80% of it is now missing... but the asker still says "you missed a spot".

I don't think that there is a logical fallacy here per se. The problem here seems to be one of three:

They keep asking because they think the question is unanswered
They keep asking because they don't care the question is answered
They keep asking because the question is unanswerable

On the first, I don't know if there is much to say by means of philosophy. I guess there is a broad sense in which there are broad societal assumptions about communication and a general risk of solipsism. Both seem like they're going a bit far in these cases. With regards to the risk report, it is probably a case of the first but in the form of how institutions operate, a formal report is a different type of entity to an informal email, the form of the communication matters. (This is grounded in more fundamental form-matter distinctions, but the road from the technical philosophy to the treatment of communication in institutions is long and I am struggling to trace this geneaology).
The Anger Management scene is an example of the second. Jack Nicholson's question is a mix of two and three. In one sense, his question has been answered in a valid way and he does not care. In another sense, it is an unanswerable question. No answer that he gets would be valid within the terms that he has set out.

+1 because I think this is getting close, and part of my problem is that I believe I'm struggling to ask the question the right way in order to get the answer I'm looking for (no, I don't mean that in the sense that I'm aiming for a biased answer but rather I want an answer to a particular question which I may not be communicating accurately). So I'm working on a new question based on this which I will add shortly.

Okay, I think this is like a risk assessment of crossing the road. I could say "the application looks right and left before crossing, and then right again as it crosses". Now you could say "well did you look through binoculars to ensure there wasn't an aircraft flying ridiculously low in the distance at 3x the speed of sound which might hit you?". Or "did you look up to make sure a meteor isn't going to drop on you?" Or perhaps "did you check that you're not crossing a volcano that's about to erupt just as you pass?". BUT you don't say any of those things.  (continued in next comment).

Instead, you suggest this is a good opportunity for me to do a risk assessment. Like it's a  great learning opportunity for me, (and you're not going to help by providing any measure you're looking for... I just get to guess). Of course I ask what you're looking for, but you are not able to give a clear answer... and continue to just try to frame this as a skill for me to develop.

It sounds like there's something here about him just 'going through the motions' of what it means to be as part of the system. He is asking because the action of asking and you re-presenting is important to him, the actual content of the assessment does not matter. It's like 2., he doesn't care that the question is answered because he has to go through the process of asking it again. This is also not a fallacy per se, but if I can take the liberty to overinterpret, I might say it's not dissimilar to Freud/Lacan's oral instinct.

@BVernon there's your problem, the app should look left first. I think this kind of thing is why I never wanted to be a manager. Being a teacher and answering the weird questions I got and assessing the outre assignments handed in was hard enough! Anyone who wants to be a manager should have his resume examined. I would like to see that next question.

Seems like there has to be a term for that, whether it's a "logical fallacy" or not, but maybe there's not.

@ScottRowe Lol, being a good manager doesn't come naturally to most. Usually people aren't put in that position because they were good at it, but because they did better than everyone else at their job and now they get promoted into a managerial position. And the sooner they learn that they're job isn't what it used to be, and that they have to completely learn how to do a new job... the better.

"Seems like there has to be a term for that, whether it's a "logical fallacy" or not, but maybe there's not." The effect of the clip is comedic by irony. Neither the clip nor the anecdote are related to reason or persuasion, which is why this post will be closed eventually.

First, The Thought Detective is absolutely right to say there is no fallacy present here. For there to be a fallacy, there must be an argument, and watching the clip, Nicholson's character does not make an argument. He asks a question over and over, so, from a philosophical perspective, we can bring two areas of knowledge to bear: rhetoric and erotetics. Both bodies of knowledge are related to what in the philosophy of language is called the perlocutionary act. From WP:

A perlocutionary act (or perlocutionary effect) is the effect of an utterance on an interlocutor.1 Examples of perlocutionary acts include persuading, convincing, scaring, enlightening, inspiring, or otherwise affecting the interlocutor.

To continue with Austin's framework, we can talk about the illocutionary and perlocutionary force. In regards to illocution, we can see that Nicholson and Sandler are engaged in erotetic discourse (read Q&A) where Nicholson attempts to elicit a piece of information from Sandler. 'Who are you?'. Obviously, there are a variety of ways that this can be answered since the question of personal identity (SEP) is a complex topic in and of itself. Sandler begins with his occupation, moves on to his hobby, asks for resolution and finally loses his temper at which point Nicholson and the group obviously telegraph and share a negative judgement about Sandler. This is the perlocutionary force.
So what has been provided so far in our analysis is simply a description of what has occurred, and the question is does rhetorical analysis apply? Since rhetoric is persuasive, we have to know whether Nicholson intends to persuade someone of something, and from the clip, it doesn't seem to be the case. We aren't provided some insight into his motivation. We have no indication of whether he has goals. But that's not a coincidence, because it establishes the comedic effect obviously through irony!
What is the irony present? Sandler is willingly trying to improve himself. He answers the questions in good faith, and seeks clarification and disambiguation required to answer the question, but eventually his character flaw, his anger, manifests itself. Who provokes his anger? The therapist, the very person who is there to help him with his anger. That's the irony; in real life, a typical therapist would understand the client has anger issues, doesn't understand the question, and wouldn't judge and tacitly endorse the client to be judged by others. The scene is written to personify forces that make Sandler feel helpless provoking his defense.
Thus, your original question really cannot be answered as its asked. The skit you provide is neither an instance of argumentation, nor is it an instance of rhetoric, so terms like fallacy and rhetorical device don't apply, because the nature of the movie scene was designed not to argue or persuade, but to elicit laughter.

To be clear, your question isn't bad, it's just shows a misapprehension of the broader nature of communication theory. Argumentation theory and rhetoric are types of communication, but so is drama, comedy, poetry, literature, and so on.

I appreciate your essay, but you've completely missed the mark. In fact you are engaging in the straw man fallacy where you are not really addressing my question and saying it's something other than it is. How so, you might ask? By saying there is no argument when in fact there very clearly is, and it has been clearly laid out. At the risk of being repetitive, I'll spell it out again: the argument is where he claims Sandler did not answer the question. I think, at this point, you have a strong bias on this question and you should not have tried to answer it in that frame of mind my friend.

I think your engagement in my question is not in good faith at this point. As I mentioned, the question already has reasonable answers and I've already marked one. If you want to close it, then vote to close it. I don't see why you need to take it personal and write something like this though.

rolls eyes You're not important enough to take your comment personal, sorry.

I'm important enough for you to feel the need to tell me about it though, apparently, lol. Hey, if you want to be useful and keep the site clean, how about you get on deleting all these useless comments we're making? ;)

Boy, you guys have really got it down! It's just like the movie clip! Nicholson's character didn't make an argument, he caused one, or two it seems. Now that's some Philosophy, just like a political debate, or the floor of the US house, or the House of Commons.

@BVernon Haha. You win! Great job. And for future questions you might ask, if I answer them, it's to exercise analysis. If an answer provides value to the OP, that's win-win. If not, I'm still ahead. But I encourage you to continue to ask questions and wield that downvote. I'm glad that it provides you some personal empowerment. :D

@JD I gave you a very specific reason why I downvoted. It was because you predicated your answer on the idea that there was no argument. But there was an argument... the argument Nicholson made was that Sandler had not answered the question. If it's your goal to provide value (to me, or anyone else), then you could update your answer appropriately and then I would gladly remove the down vote. The vote wasn't based on my assessment of your opinions, but on that of a crucial and foundational fact you got wrong.

Let it go. It'll be okay.
